# How to create counttdown when I show a after a letter?

Tags: python

When I show the letter "A" I want a countdown to start from 4. While the countdown is running I want to be able to create a new letter. When I type a new letter, the first countdown should be aborted and the countdown of the new letter should start from 4. How can I do this?

```
import time
import copy

def countdown(t):
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1

    print('FINISH!!')

sign = input ("Enter text: ")
copySign = copy.deepcopy(sign)

if sign == copySign:
    countdown(int(4))
```

Comment: Much much much harder than that. I assume you're too novice to wrap your head around it. The problem is in time.sleep(1) which would make your application unresponsive for 1 second. You would need to sleep for a smaller period of time (like 0.05, which is 50 millisec) and then call some non-blocking input, which is the hardest part. To make it easy you can try to install `inputimeout` package for it

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is interesting  and tricky
What I can think of is that you can use threading library to run two separate functions as threads which run simultaneously 
In this way you'll not only be able to run a countdown, but also check if user is typing a new letter or not.